# Need to extract special tags and replace them based upon their contents using regular expression

Tags: php, regex

I'm working on a simple templating system. Basically I'm setting it up such that a user would enter text populated with special tags of the form: `<== variableName ==>`

When the system would display the text it would search for all tags of the form mentioned and replace the variableName with its corresponding value from a database result.

I think this would require a regular expression but I'm really messed up in REGEX here. I'm using php btw.

Thanks for the help guys.

Comment: Call it YATS: Yet another Template System - No, seriously, why reinvent the wheel? PHP by itself is already a template engine. If you need a 3rd party Template System, why not use one of the many freely available, like Twig or Smarty or [insert favorite framework here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_engine_%28web%29). And if you really need to do your own, then why not go full length and make those *tags* actually tags, e.g. elements with a namespace, like `<my:var id="foo"/>`. Then you can use DOM for the replacements.

Comment: Thanks but its not exactly a template system in teh fullest sense of the word - my system creates email requests and need to create the emails in a specific format. The templating system just grabs values from a database to preset the emails. The client in this case needed a way to define the templates himself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A rather quick and dirty hack here:

```
<?php

$teststring = "Hello <== tag ==>";

$values = array();

$values['tag'] = "world";


function replaceTag($name)
{
    global $values;
    return $values[$name];
}

echo preg_replace('/<== ([a-z]*) ==>/e','replaceTag(\'$1\')',$teststring);
```

Output:

```
Hello world
```

Simply place your 'variables' in the variable array and they will be replaced.

The `e` modifier to the regular expression tells it to eval the replacement, the `[a-z]` lets you name the "variables" using the characters a-z (you could use [a-z0-9] if you wanted to include numbers). Other than that its pretty much standard PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Very useful - Pointed me to what I was looking for...

Replacing tags in a template e.g.

```
<<page_title>>, <<meta_description>>
```

with corresponding request variables e,g,

```
$_REQUEST['page_title'], $_REQUEST['meta_description'],
```

using a modified version of the code posted:

```
$html_output=preg_replace('/<<(\w+)>>/e', '$_REQUEST[\'$1\']', $template);
```

Easy to change this to replace template tags with values from a DB etc...

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing a simple replace, then you don't need to use a regexp. You can just use [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) which is **quicker**.

(I'm assuming your '<== ' and ' ==>' are delimiting your template var and are replaced with your value?)

```
$subject = str_replace('<== '.$varName.' ==>', $varValue, $subject);
```

And to cycle through all your template vars...

```
$tplVars = array();
$tplVars['ONE'] = 'This is One';
$tplVars['TWO'] = 'This is Two';
// etc.

// $subject is your original document
foreach ($tplVars as $varName => $varValue) {
  $subject = str_replace('<== '.$varName.' ==>', $varValue, $subject);
}
```

Comment: Nice idea but the thing is that I don't want to run through my entire list of possible variables rather I wish to find and replace only those variables which do exist in the template.